# В терминале при установке выводит сообщение об лицензеонном соглашении и нету кнопки продолжить

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Устанавливаю Wine на ubuntu и выводит в терминале такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не понимаю что я должен нажимать или делать

Comment: Попробуйте Tab. Должна выделиться кнопка Ok. Потом нажмите Enter.

Comment: Вон же кнопка `<Ok>` есть

Comment: спасибо, да надо было на неё табом навестись и enter

Comment: Если вы согласны с условиями лицензии  — нажимайте <Ok>!